# Why in app purchase title app store localization was rejected?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Thanks for view post.

I found some problem on step review in-app-purchase.

All item in app purchase hold on "Developer Action Needed" then I check issue i found it because all item in section App Store Localization rejected.

I don't know why it rejected on board don't show any information that why it was rejected.

if who know please suggest me.

I try many renew create item but every i resume for submit it every time it was reject aways

I attached example my rejected image below

thanks.

[image]

Comment: You probably need a better description than simply repeating the display name. You should also probably correct the spelling and capitalisation (assuming you are referring to a chocolate cake type of thing)  e.g. "A brownie" "Feed brownies to your elves to improve their magical abilities for 12 hours" or whatever.  Describe what the purchaser gets and why they would purchase it.

Comment: Did you figure this out with Apple?